# Word search within texts to find text that contains most matched variant

Tags: sql, sql-server, algorithm, cpu-word, fuzzy-comparison

I want to find a way to find most suitable row from table which contains a word that is most similar to the word i'm entering. any idea? (I'm using OCR that finds words not exactly the same sometimes reads word 'specific' as 'spccific')

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Oracle then you can try [UTL_MATCH](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e10577/u_match.htm#CHDJBBCE) which uses something known as the [Levenshtein Distance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance) to calculate the minimum number of edits to transform one string into another. Other systems may have something similar or you can use the alogrithm as a starting point for your own function.

Comment: unfortunately, i'm using mssql. but i 'll  try to write a function which utl_match does. but i've hoped there is a same function in mssql :(

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use the `SOUNDEX` functionality (SQL Server)  or `SOUNDS LIKE` (MySQL) if it is available with the SQL engine you are using.

Comment: phonetics is not a good solution. also, language of database is not english